# Is it possible to adjust position of gdigrab recording region during recording?

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg for recording video from defined desktop region by starting ffmpeg.exe as process with arguments like so:

```
    public static void StartRecording(Video v) {
        string outPath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "rec", $"{v.FileName}.mkv");
        v.FFMPEG = new Process {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() {
                Arguments = $"-hide_banner -y -thread_queue_size 512 -f gdigrab -offset_x {v.Bounds.X} -offset_y {v.Bounds.Y} -video_size {v.Bounds.Width}x{v.Bounds.Height} -show_region 0 -i desktop -vf \"scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2\" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p \"{outPath}\"",
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                FileName = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "bin", "ffmpeg.exe"),
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
            }
        };
        v.FFMPEG.Start();

        new Thread(() => {
            using(StreamReader sr = v.FFMPEG.StandardError) {
                while(!sr.EndOfStream) {
                    Debug.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
                }
            }
        }).Start();
    }

    public static void StopRecording(Video v) {
        using(StreamWriter sw = v.FFMPEG.StandardInput) {
            sw.WriteLine("q\n");
        }
        v.FFMPEG.WaitForExit();
        v.FFMPEG.Dispose();
    }
```

Is it possible to make changes to the `-offset_x` and `-offset_y` arguments during recording? I'm drawing the recording region bounds with directx and want to add a titlebar to it which can be dragged to move the recording region, but I'm not sure how I would let ffmpeg know that I want these offsets changed or whether it's even possible.

Comment: Those can't be changed after init. If you can refer to the window using a process title, then you can move it around.

Comment: It's not a window, it's a desktop region. The "title" I was referring to is a custom title drawn with directx specific to the recording region defined. Though I suppose maybe I could spawn an invisible window and use that as the recording source, but seems hacky and not sure if ffmpeg would record it correctly.

Comment: Just tested this possible solution with disappointing results, seems ffmpeg specifically wants to record from a window's graphics if the title is set. So if the window is transparent, ffmpeg just records a black box. I suppose my only solution is to build ffmpeg myself with a modification to gdigrab.